# How to inherit directory directives in apache conf file

Tags: apache

My google-fu always fails me with getting help on apache.

For example, I have following directives:

```
<Directory /path/toVhostRoot> 
Options none 
Satisfy all 
Order allow,deny 
</Directory>
```

and I make a subdir with just:

```
<Directory /path/toVhostRoot/subdir> 
Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

Now I want-

```
Options none 
Satisfy all 
Order allow,deny
```

Should be inherited by the subdir, but this is not happening. Any way to achieve this?

This is just an example to demonstrate what I want, these are not actual directives on which I want to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practicing my google-fu for another day helped me fix the problem. Answering so that I get blessings from anyone who comes across this ever.

What I did is simply add the common directives into a separate directives.conf

```
Options none 
Satisfy all 
Order allow,deny
```

And now Include this in whichever directory directive I want it.

```
<Directory /path/toVhostRoot> 
  Include /path/to/directives.conf
</Directory>

<Directory /path/toVhostRoot/subdir>
  Include /path/to/directives.conf
  Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply shell-style wildcard characters to the path in your Directory directive, so that

```
<Directory "/path/toVhostRoot*">
 ... common directives group
</Directory>
```

Such a way `"... common directives"` group will be applyed not only to root dir, but also to it's subdirs.

If more complex matching roule is needed, then it is possible to use `<DirectoryMatch>` directives instead which is compatible with regular expression (regex) sintax.

As far I can see `wildcard` and `regex` in `<Directory>` and `<DirectoryMatch>` are sopported by apache starting from [1.3 revision](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#directory).

Check your [web server manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) to verify such option.